# Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am a very new programmer that was challenged to make a bitcoin clicking game. I am about ten percent done and have spent hours trying to debug my site. I get this error. Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick It all worked perfectly fine until I added a upgrade function. After that it did not work. Not even deleted it made a difference.

```
<script>
    function update() {
        document.getElementById('text').value = bitcoincount;
        document.title = bitcoincount + " Bitcoin";
        document.getElementById('amountithree').innerHTML = "You Own " + ithree + " i3's";

    }

    var bitcoincount = 0;
    var ithree = 0;

    function timer() {
        bitcoincount = bitcoincount + ithree;
        update()
    }

    setInterval(timer, 1000)

</script>
<html>
<head><title>Bitcoin</title></head>
<body>

<a href=# onclick="add()"><img src="opengraph.png" height="200" width="200"></a>
<br><br>
You got:
<input type="text" id="text" disabled style=text-align:center>
<script>
    function add() {
        bitcoincount = bitcoincount + 1
        document.getElementById('text').value
        bitcoincount;
        document.title = bitcoincount + " Bitcoin";
    }
</script>
Bitcoin.
<br><br>


<button><a href="#" onclick="save()">Save</a></button>
<button><a href="#" onclick="load()">Load</a></button>
<br><br>
<p>Buy 1 i3 6100</p>
<button><a href="#" onclick="buyithree"><img src=ithree.jpg width="100" height="100"></a></button>
<p id="costithree"> Bitcoin</p>
<p id="amountithree">You Own 0 i3's</p>

<script>
    function save() {
        localStorage.setItem("bitcoincount", bitcoincount);
    }

    function load() {
        bitcoincount = localStorage.getItem("bitcoincount");
        bitcoincount = parseInt(bitcoincount);
        update()
    }

    function buyithree() {
        if (bitcoincount >= ((ithree + 1) ^ 12)) {
            bitcoincount = bitcoincount - ((ithree + 1) ^ 12);
            update()
        }

    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this is not the issue, but `onclick="buyithree"` is wrong.
Why do you have a script before the html tag?

Comment: Learn to use your developer tools: `{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",` you click on it and it takes you right to the error. Your add function is wrong, you have a line missing an equals.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but I'd move the first `<script...>...</script>` block to be inside the `<html>...</html>` block, preferably inside `<head>...</head>`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your `add()` function, that's why the browser can't recognize it

```
document.getElementById('text').value bitcoincount;
```

should be :

```
document.getElementById('text').value = bitcoincount;
```

Comment: you're welcome :) i'm glad i could help , ( don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :P )

Answer (score 0):

Your function have error thats why its not created Please ckeck console for errors
Change this add assignment operator

```
document.getElementById('text').value = bitcoincount;
```